# Exoplayer stops working and shows blank screen after playing for 22-25 times in recyclerview

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-studio-3.0, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Firebase Recyclerview in my app. I have an exoplayer embedded in each item of the recycler view. Everything works fine, but after scrolling through around 22-25 items, exoplayer stops to load and play the video. And I get the following error

> ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error.     com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [576, 1024, 25.0], [-1, -1])

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used to do similar things with and faced with the same issue.In my app, I play many videos in viewpager.The issue is that the player and the video format decoder is limited in a mobile,you need to reuse them instead of creating news ones.We make a global pool with a limit of 5 players totally.You just acquire and relase it according to your demands.And the error will not happen anymore.

Comment: Hii, we had a similar issue in playing the video in Flutter, can you tell me how to release the expo instance resource and reuse them accordingly